# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted

Tags: sql-server

i am getting this error while executing the procedure. This problem occurs only at production not in the testing and developer systems. Also this problem does not occur all the time. When this error arises all users using this database through application are getting hanged that means all the users connections to the database are reset. It resumes and works fine after few seconds.

The error message is

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
   at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Project1.Library.dbconn.OpenConn()
   at Project1.Library.clsUserMenuDAL.SubChildMenu(clsUserMenuBAL obj)
```

The stored procedure that i am using is given below,

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_LoadMainMenu]  
 @User_Gid [int] = 0,  
 @profile_gid [int] = 0,  
 @soft_gid [int] = 0  

WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER  
AS  
BEGIN  
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    -- Insert statements for procedure here  
    declare @lsquery varchar(max)  
 set @lsquery=' select menu_gid,menu_desc,menu_link,menu_reportorder from qad_adm_tmenu a '  
 set @lsquery =@lsquery+' inner join qad_adm_tprofilerights b on b.profilerights_menugid=a.menu_gid'  
 set @lsquery =@lsquery+' inner join qad_map_tuserprofile c on c.userprofile_profilerightsgid=b.profilerights_gid'  
 set @lsquery =@lsquery+' where c.Userprofile_usergid ='+ convert(varchar(20),@User_Gid) + 'and c.userprofile_profilegid = ' + convert(varchar(20),@profile_gid) + ''  
 set @lsquery =@lsquery+' and a.menu_softgid= '+ convert(varchar(20),@soft_gid) +' and a.menu_ordernumber =2'  
 set @lsquery =@lsquery+' and c.Userprofile_isremoved = ''N'' and userprofile_profilerightsaccess=''Y''  
 order by menu_reportorder '  

 exec(@lsquery)  

END
```

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: What version of sql server are you using - 2008R2, 2012 ? Also, can you run the SP directly from SSMS and you face the same issue ? Also, what is the timeout set on your application ?

Comment: It appears this is an error on the client app, not on the server. From the callstack it appears the exception occurs while opening the connection. You'll need to post your application code and connection string. I've voted to migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you making a connection to a linked server?

Comment: I m using Sql Server 2008. I m not facing this issue while run this Sp from SSMS. It occurs only when used from the application. Even in Application this problem does not arise all the time.

Comment: The Connection string that i am using has pooling as false.

Comment: @sathya "The Connection string that i am using has pooling as false" That is usually not a good idea. You probably meant to fix some problem doing that, but you didn't fix the problem. You just hid it. Enable pooling and fix the underlying issue.

Comment: Adam Zuckerman , no linked server connections are made.

Comment: @usr i have enabled the pooling to true, but still same error arises. Does it relates to db connection timeout. Do i need to specify command timeout in the code.

Answer (score 1):

> his problem occurs only at production not in the testing and developer systems.

I'll guess: ASP.NET aborted your request processing due to a timeout using `Thread.Abort`. Increase the timeout or optimize the SQL work.

> When this error arises all users using this database through application are getting hanged

Probably, because you are not correctly disposing of database connections, thereby leaving open connections, transactions and locks. Put everything into `using` statements. Why wouldn't you?

> that means all the users connections to the database are reset

I don't think this is true. Do you have any evidence for that?

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have put time out to Five Hundred Billon seconds. I have disposed the connection properly using the try,catch,finally statements to dispose the connection object after the execution.

Comment: The SQL timeouts are not the problem. ASP.NET is aborting the request. Increase the ASP.NET request timeout.

Comment: 'that means all the users connections to the database are reset'- i think it is true because the message come to all the users who tries to access the Stored Procedures. But it works fine after while when user refresh the page.

Comment: What message exactly? Probably a timeout due to blocking. Is there evidence that the connections are severed? Anyway, did you try to ASP.NET suggestion?

Comment: The same error message (Threat being aborted) for all the users. The Asp.net time out was 3600 seconds. No clear evidence to say connections are terminated but the same error message was received by all the user.

Comment: @sathya ok I kind of buy that. There's something going on for all users. Maybe the app pool recycled. Anyway, I'm out of ideas. Good luck!