# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am working on asp.net with mysql. Getting some exceptions while accessing db (only in production)

StackStrace-1:

```
at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()
   at Web_Report_ACKReport.ExportDataTableToCSV(DataTable dataTable)
```

StackStrace-2:

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Ping()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at project.Data.ObjDIO.getDbConn(String connectionString)
   at project.Data.AdoCompat.ConnectionObjects.OpenConnection()
   at myProject.projName.DAL.DAL.Insert(String strFileName, Int32 totalRecords, Int32 insertedCount, Int32 queueId, Int32 reviewType, String strCreatedUser)
   at BusinessLayer.Queue.QueueSupport.Create(String strFileName, Int32 totalRecords, Int32 insertedCount, Int32 queueId, Int32 reviewType, String strCreatedUser)
```

DB Connection string: `<add name="dbconnection" connectionString="server=dbserver; initial catalog=sampledv;user id=dbuser;password=dbpassword;pooling=true;" providerName="system.data.mysqlclient"/>`

Help me to fix this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323205/system-threading-threadabortexception-thread-was-being-aborted

Answer (score 0):

you should use `uid` instead of User ID of the SQL query string

your connection string is looks like

```
<add name="dbconnectionstring" connectionString="server=dbserver; initial catalog=sampledv;uid=dbuser;password=dbpassword;pooling=true;" providerName="system.data.mysqlclient"/>
```

Comment: have you got your answer or not ? @Ganesh